# Error when combing two columns: ValueError: Columns must be same lenght as key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and am working with pandas. The dataframe has many columns and I am trying to combine a few of them.
In the example below I want to combine the year value of the calv1 and calv2 columns seperatly with the herd column and get an integer values -> herd+calv1 = HC1 & herd+calv2 = HC2

```
     #datetime   #datetime #int    #New columns I am trying to create
id       calv1       calv2  herd       HC1       HC2
1   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  1222  12222006  12222006  
2          NaT         NaT  1222  12220000  12220000 
3   2006-08-29         NaT  1222  12222006  12220000 
4   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  2334  13342006  13342007
5   2006-08-29  2013-08-29  1333  13332006  13342013
6   2006-08-29         NaT  1333  13332006  13340000
```

This what I've tried:

```
df[['HC1','HC2']] =((df[['herd','herd']
    ].apply(
    lambda s: s * 10000
    ))
    +
    (df[['calv1','calv2']
    ].apply(
    lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y').replace('NaT', '0').astype(int)
    ))
)
```

Multiply the herd by *10000 and adding the year.

But when I try I get the error marked in the first line of the code:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Can somebody help me see what going wrong? Am I not doing the apply and lambda correctly ?
If I exclude the first part of the equation and only find the year it works but when I add the first part it doesn't.

Also if somebody has an Idea how I could do this and leave blank values where there are no observations I would love to see it:

```
     #datetime   #datetime #int    #New columns I am trying to create
id       calv1       calv2  herd       HC1       HC2
1   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  1222  12222006  12222006  
2          NaT         NaT  1222         0         0 
3   2006-08-29         NaT  1222  12222006         0 
4   2006-08-29  2007-08-29  2334  13342006  13342007
5   2006-08-29  2013-08-29  1333  13332006  13342013
6   2006-08-29         NaT  1333  13332006         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with [`dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html#pandas-series-dt-year) and math operations followed by [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) to replace `NaN` with `0`:

```
s = df['herd'] * 10000
df['HC1'] = s + df['calv1'].dt.year
df['HC2'] = s + df['calv2'].dt.year
df[['HC1', 'HC2']] = df[['HC1', 'HC2']].fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

`df`:

```
   id      calv1      calv2  herd       HC1       HC2
0   1 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  1222  12222006  12222007
1   2        NaT        NaT  1222         0         0
2   3 2006-08-29        NaT  1222  12222006         0
3   4 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  2334  23342006  23342007
4   5 2006-08-29 2013-08-29  1333  13332006  13332013
5   6 2006-08-29        NaT  1333  13332006         0
```

For the first output with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) to fill `NaT` with `2000`:

```
s = df['herd'] * 10000
df['HC1'] = s + df['calv1'].dt.year.fillna(2000, downcast='infer')
df['HC2'] = s + df['calv2'].dt.year.fillna(2000, downcast='infer')
```

`df`:

```
   id      calv1      calv2  herd       HC1       HC2
0   1 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  1222  12222006  12222007
1   2        NaT        NaT  1222  12222000  12222000
2   3 2006-08-29        NaT  1222  12222006  12222000
3   4 2006-08-29 2007-08-29  2334  23342006  23342007
4   5 2006-08-29 2013-08-29  1333  13332006  13332013
5   6 2006-08-29        NaT  1333  13332006  13332000
```

---

DataFrame Constructor and Imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'calv1': ['2006-08-29', None, '2006-08-29', '2006-08-29', '2006-08-29',
              '2006-08-29'],
    'calv2': ['2007-08-29', None, None, '2007-08-29', '2013-08-29', None],
    'herd': [1222, 1222, 1222, 2334, 1333, 1333]
})
df['calv1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calv1'])
df['calv2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calv2'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the first part works very well.